# Conversion of JRadioButton to Boolean?

Tags: java, radio-button, boolean, project

I'm trying to make it so that depending on whether or not a radio button is pressed it will use the Java Graphics and create an applet with a preset drawing on it. Although I tried to use an if statement but it tells me I cannot convert JRadioButton to boolean, but I feel like this wouldn't be the right way to go about this. I'm pulling my hair because I don't understand how to do this.

Help/Guidance would be greatly appreciated :D ! Thanks !

My code looks like this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class RadioButton extends JPanel {

    static JFrame frame;

   JLabel pic;
   RadioListener myListener = null;
   public RadioButton() {



       // Create the radio buttons and assign Keyboard shortcuts using Mnemonics
       JRadioButton displacement = new JRadioButton("Displacement");
       displacement.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N);
       displacement.setSelected(true);
        //Displacement Button, set to automatically be clicked

       JRadioButton accel = new JRadioButton("Acceleration");
       accel.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
       accel.setActionCommand("acceleration");
        //Acceleration Button

       JRadioButton time = new JRadioButton("Change in time");
       time.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);
       time.setActionCommand("deltaT");
        //The change in time button

       // Creates the group of buttons
       ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
       group.add(displacement);
       group.add(accel);
       group.add(time);

              myListener = new RadioListener();
                displacement.addActionListener(myListener);
                accel.addActionListener(myListener);
                time.addActionListener(myListener);


      // Set up the picture label
       pic = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(""+"numbers" + ".jpg"));          //Set the Default Image

       pic.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(177, 122)); 


       // Puts the radio buttons down
       JPanel panel = new JPanel();
       panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
       panel.add(displacement);
       panel.add(accel);
       panel.add(time);


       setLayout(new BorderLayout());
       add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
       add(pic, BorderLayout.CENTER);
       setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(40,40,40,40));
   } 
  if ( displacement.setSelected(true))
  {

  }


   //Listening to the buttons
   class RadioListener implements ActionListener { 
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           pic.setIcon(new ImageIcon(""+e.getActionCommand() 
                                         + ".jpg"));
       }
   }

   public static void main(String s[]) {
        frame = new JFrame("∆x = Vavg * time");
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
```

Comment: I still need to make a class where the applet will run from but I need to get it to change whether or not it is pressed

Answer (score 2):

You are setting `true` to `isSelected()`. However, based on your description, you want to check if it was selected.

Use:

```
if ( displacement.isSelected())
  {

  }
```

Instead of:

```
if ( displacement.setSelected(true))
  {

  }
```

Comment: Quick Question: when I do that, I am doing it in a different class and it says that the variable displacement cannot be resolved. I extended the other class, but that didn't work, so how do I get it so that it can get to the variable displacement.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what to do about that, so if someone could help me out that would be awesome!